# Closest thing to an is_widget() tag?

Tags: widgets, conditional-tags

I have a custom widget with a WP_Query loop that's using `get_template_part()` to include some standard information that I also use in theme files. However, I need to make one small change to the widget's output that differs from the template file I grab with `get_template_part()`. I know I could copy the template file and modify it, but then I have to maintain two sets of that code. What I'd prefer is something like an `is_widget()` check that I could use like:

```
if( !is_widget() ) {
    // include an extra goody
}
```

I know there is no `is_widget()`, but is there some other WordPress thing I can look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you insist using get_template_part, the only solution I see is to define a global variable in your widget's widget() function, and set it to true or something.

After you call get_template_part in your widget, set this variable to false. Within your template check for that variable, and if it's true, it means you are within the widget.

A better way is to use `locate_template` and do the inclusion yourself. That way you can control what variables are exposed in your template, so you can pass a normal variable to your template:

```
$_located = locate_template('template-name', false, false);

$in_widget = true; // not global :D      

// load it;
// any variables you have here will also be available in your template 

if($_located)
  require $_located;
```

In your template:

```
if(isset($in_widget)){
  //
}
```

A different way, without using that context variable:

```
if(isset($this) && ($this instanceof YourWidgetClass)){
  //
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is pretty much as close as I was expecting, so I have no problem accepting is as correct. One quick note: According to the codex, the first parameter of `locate_template()` is an array. I needed the array anyway (I was using the second paramter of `get_template_part()` before), but I think you'd need it even for the single entry like in your example.

Comment: not really, because whatever argument you give, it will be casted to array...